# Let $a_i$ , $1\le i\le n$ be non-negative real numbers. Let S denote their sum.Pick out the true statements:

Tags: products

Let $a_i$ , $1\le i\le n$ be non-negative real numbers. Let S denote their sum.Pick out the true statements:

(a)$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(1+a_k)\ge1+S}$
(b)$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(1+a_k)\le1+\frac{S}{1!}}+\frac{S^2}{2!}+....\frac{S^n}{n!}$
(c)$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(1+a_k)\ge \frac{1}{1-S}}$ if $S<1$

Comment: Try for some small $n$, $n = 2,3,4$ should give you strong hints.

Answer (score 0):

(a) and (b) by induction

(c)  Take n=1 and have wrong statement. Opposite unequlity is true. Also by induction can be proved.

Comment: c) If you put $S<1$ and then see that $\frac{S^n}{n!}\leq S^n$. Then add all the higher order term to see that less than equality hold. Then from b check the $\leq$ wil be true.